# Successful API build, but now what

Tags: rest, powerbi

So I am pretty much self taught on SharePoint and have just recently built a Rest API off one of my lists. Now say I wanted to ingest that API into a program like power BI? is that possible? I guess my question is what would be my next steps for exporting/ingesting the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST data can be consumed by just about everything: JavaScript, C#, PowerShell, and of course Power BI.

1. Launch Power BI Desktop
2. Click Get Data from the ribbon
3. Click OData Feed.
4. Enter a URL to a SharePoint web service. This one retrieves all Touring bikes.
   This example assumes a list named “Bikes for Power BI”
   Example: 
   https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Bikes for Power BI')/Items?$filter=category eq ' Touring'
5. Click OK.
6. Find and checkmark your SharePoint list.
7. Review your data and click Edit. (SharePoint adds a number of hidden/internal columns that you will probably want to exclude.)
8. Optional: In the Query Settings area, click in the Name box and enter a new name for the imported data.
9. Select all of the columns that you do not need and click Remove Columns. Or, select the columns you want to keep, click the dropdown under Remove Columns, and click Remove Other Columns.
   For the class’s example list, keep the bikeID, color, category, size and price columns.
10. Click Close & Apply.
11. Create your visuals!